# php process xml readfile

Tags: php, xml, file-io

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3673989/2118559 read that to get xml content better to use `readfile`, because it is the fastest.

I want to get and process content from here http://api.stopforumspam.org/api?ip=91.186.18.61

I did

```
readfile( "http://api.stopforumspam.org/api?ip=91.186.18.61" );
```

Then if result contains word `no` I will continue.

Like

```
if( strpos( 
readfile( "http://api.stopforumspam.org/api?ip=". urlencode(get_ip_address()) ),'no'     
) === true ){
echo ' continue<br>';
}
```

But it does not work. As understand `readfile` as if `echo` content of the file.

Do I need to use `file_get_contents` (can not do it with `readfile`)?

**Edited**

In above example I used wrong condition. Need for example `!== false`.

But remains problem that such code

```
readfile( "http://api.stopforumspam.org/api?ip=91.186.18.61" );
```

echo in my website content of xml file. like  `ip yes 2013-10-07 13:19:05 2`

Do not need to echo (do not need to show visitor, that his ip address is in spam list or no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `file_get_contents` and `!==false`

try this

```
if( strpos(file_get_contents("http://api.stopforumspam.org/api?ip=". urlencode(get_ip_address()) ),'no') !== false ){
echo ' continue<br>';
}
```

Comment: Condition works. But I see as if echo `ip no 0 `. Do not want to see. The condition `if...` as if echo `ip no 0 `.

Answer (score 0):

You should use file_get_content

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.stopforumspam.com/api?ip=91.186.18.61");
$chk = strpos($data, 'yes');
if($chk === false)
{
    echo ' continue<br>';
}
```

I have checked the code its working.

Comment: In my situation problem is that in website I see content of file. This `$data = file_get_contents("http://www.stopforumspam.com/api?ip=91.186.18.61");` as if echo content

Comment: `strpos` never return `true`. it will return `false` or  position of the `substring`

Comment: @SKRocks i have  just edited the answer it was a typo i copied from the question thanks